# Plotting time series + offset not working

Tags: time-series, gnuplot

I want to plot two time series that are in different formats in the
same format, but one of those two doesn't work for me.

So here's the thing: 
I have a time series in seconds with a given starting time t0.

So the series looks like this: 
Starting time: t0

0   -21.0028 
5   -21.0067 
10  -21.007  
...          
17875   -20.9943

I want to plot this time series with the time (e.g. 9:03) instead
of seconds and I want to show another time series where the
data is given in standard time in the same plot.

I can plot the second series just fine.
But when I try to plot the first series, the measured points
start jumping from x=100 back to 0 and then back and forth.
Additionally I can't add the offset t0 to the series.

Here's what I tried (t0 = 32615s) to get at least the first time series plotted:

gnuplot> set xdata time 
gnuplot> set timefmt "%S" 
gnuplot> set format x "%H:%M" 
gnuplot> plot 'measurement.dat' u (timecolumn(1)+32615):2 w l, 'measurement2.dat" u 1:2 w l

Does anyone know how I can plot these time series?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you have two data sets with different timedata. One in seconds and the other what you call "standard", I assume, e.g. `09:03:00`.
And you want to shift the one with seconds by some value.
Internally, dates and times are stored as seconds from January 1st 1970 00:00:00.
Since the first dataset is already in seconds just add your shift-value.
You need to convert ´$Data2´ into seconds via `timecolumn(1,"%H:%M:%S")`.
And the way you display the xtic labels is set via `set format x "%H:%M" time`. Also check `help timecolumn`. It also depends if you want to display a time of the day, i.e. 00:00 to 23:59 or if you want to display hours >24h. Then you might want to use `"%tH:%tM:%tS"`as format. Check `help time_specifiers`.

**Code:**

```
### shifted time data
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data1
    do for [i=1:20000:200] {
        print sprintf("%d %.3f",i,sin(i/2000.))
    }
set print
set print $Data2
    do for [i=30000:50000:200] {
        print sprintf("%s %.3f",strftime("%H:%M:%S",i),2*sin(i/2000.-2.5))
    }
set print

set format x "%H:%M" time
set key top center

set multiplot layout 2,1
    plot $Data1 u 1:2 w lp ti "Data1", \
         $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,"%H:%M:%S")):2 w lp ti "Data2"

    t0 = 30000
    plot $Data1 u ($1+t0):2 w lp ti "shifted Data1", \
         $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,"%H:%M:%S")):2 w lp title "Data2"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]